# Search across multiple tables with joins using Oracle Text

Tags: oracle, indexing, full-text-search, oracle10g, oracle-text

*(Note: This question is [cross-posted from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/q/214315/59289).)*

I need to perform oracle text search across multiple tables in my oracle 10g database. The tables have the following structures:

```
Table1 (ID, col1, col2, ...)
SubTable1 (ID, Table1ID, col1, col2, ...)
SubTable2 (ID, Table1ID, col1, col2, ...)
```

Table1 has one-to-n relationships to both SubTable1 and Subtable2.

At runtime, a client application will provide the search terms to search across the three tables. Only records from either one of the tables that contains the search terms should be joined together and returned to the client application.

#### Scenario (simplified example)

If a record in Table1 has 10 records in SubTable1 but only 4 out of the 10 contain the search terms, only 4 rows should be returned to the client application. Same goes to SubTable2.

#### The Question

Is there a way to do this with minimal changes, ideally with only one `contains` search across all tables? Or do I really need to specify one `contains` for each table?

#### Additional Note

- I followed [this](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.databases.oracle.server/browse_thread/thread/17dd4ddcf30936b3/f6e6d73b417397d8?hide_quotes=no&hl=en&pli=1) and tried creating a dummy text index column in Table1 with preference `User_Datastore`. A stored procedure is used to retrieve and format all the related data from all the tables in XML format. This does not work because all 10 records in SubTable1 (stated in Scenario) will be returned instead. The row in Table1 matches the search term and then joins with all 10 rows in Subtable1.

Comment: What is the relationship between SUBTABLE1 and SUBTABLE2?  If SUBTABLE1 has four matching rows and SUBTABLE2 has two matching rows, how many rows from TABLE1 should we get?

Comment: @APC: There is no direct relationship between SubTable1 and SubTable2, they are only linked via Table1. There should be six rows in the result table.

Comment: I'm very late, but… isn't a materialized view possible?